# What's wrong with my boost phoenix lazy function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I have the following code (using boost 1.55 on MSVC9):

```
struct pair_first_impl
{
   template<class TPair> struct result { typedef typename TPair::first_type type; };

   template<class TPair>
   typename TPair::first_type const& operator() (TPair const& pair) const
   {
      return pair.first;
   }

   template<class TPair>
   typename TPair::first_type& operator() (TPair& pair)
   {
      return pair.first;
   }
};

static phx::function<pair_first_impl> pair_first;

int test()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), pair_first(_1) == 1);
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error regarding `pair_first_impl::result::type`, which says:

```
error C2825: 'TPair': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
see reference to class template instantiation 'pair_first_impl::result<TPair>' being compiled
        with
        [
            TPair=const pair_first_impl (std::pair<const int,std::string> )
        ]
```

For some reason, it looks like it is passing in a function type (?) into my `TPair` template argument instead of the `std::pair` type directly.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I know it is not the final goal but can you specialize `pair_first_impl::operator()` for `std::pair<int, std::string>`? If that works that might mean that `template<...> operator()` is too greedy and it is taking everything as argument, even other lazy functions (like `_1` itself).

Comment: Also, I think there is a `phoenix:at_c<0>` that can do this, I can't find it now. Please post if anything of this worked.

Comment: I know about at_c but isn't very self documenting, so I'd rather create a lazy function.

Comment: I think it is used simply `boost::phoenix::at_c<0>(_1)`, it is defined in `boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp`, however you may need to make `std::pair` an adapted fusion sequence first. I'll put this as a an answer to make the code more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by reviewing [the result_of protocol documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of) (which is separate from phoenix; I was expecting phoenix docs to explain):

```
struct pair_first_impl
{
   template<class> struct result;

   template<class F, class TPair>
   struct result<F(TPair)>
   {
      typedef typename boost::remove_reference<TPair>::type actual_type;
      typedef typename actual_type::first_type type;
   };

   template<class TPair>
   typename TPair::first_type const& operator() (TPair const& pair) const
   {
      return pair.first;
   }

   template<class TPair>
   typename TPair::first_type& operator() (TPair& pair)
   {
      return pair.first;
   }
};

static phx::function<pair_first_impl> pair_first;

int test()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), pair_first(_1) == 1);
   return 0;
}
```

The problem was that I thought that the type passed into the template parameter for the nested `result` struct was the type of the first parameter, which it isn't. It's actually the whole function type. So a template specialization of `result` must be created the can be used to extract the type of the first argument. You can then use this to access `first_type` in the pair.

My `_1` placeholder is valid because at the top of my source file I'm doing the following:

```
using namespace boost::phoenix::placeholders;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong placeholder `_1`. You need one that is actually a phoenix actor:

```
std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), pair_first(phx::placeholders::_1) == 1);
```

OTOH, your functor has inconsistent `result_type` protocol. This might not bite you when you use `BOOST_SPIRIT_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE`. Why don't you just use a `bind`? This will get all the deduction correct for you without the work:

```
using namespace phx::arg_names;

void test()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;

   using Pair = std::pair<const int, std::string>;
   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), phx::bind(&Pair::first, arg1) == 1);
}
```

Of course, you can detect the pair-type if you want.

Full code **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2d8419993fc0292)**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct pair_first_impl
{
   template<class TPair> struct result { typedef typename TPair::first_type const& type; };

   template<class TPair>
   typename TPair::first_type const& operator() (TPair const& pair) const {
      return pair.first;
   }

   template<class TPair>
   typename TPair::first_type& operator() (TPair& pair) {
      return pair.first;
   }
};

static phx::function<pair_first_impl> pair_first;


void test1()
{
   using phx::placeholders::_1;

   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), pair_first(_1) == 1);
}

void test2()
{
   using Pair = std::pair<const int, std::string>;
   using namespace phx::arg_names;

   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), phx::bind(&Pair::first, arg1) == 1);
}

void test3()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
   using Pair = decltype(mymap)::value_type;
   using namespace phx::arg_names;

   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), phx::bind(&Pair::first, arg1) == 1);
}

int main()
{
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but it gives a workaround that is based on existing implementation: (untested code)

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion/at.hpp>
...
int test()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> mymap;
   std::find_if(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), boost::phoenix::at_c<0>(_1) == 1);
}
```

(This without even mention that with C++11 Lambdas you don't need any of this)

Even if this works, your question is a valid one. I suggest two experiments, 
1) use `enable_if` to discard `TPair` if it is a phoenix expression. 2) Make your `operator()` more specific to `std::pair`, like this:

```
   ...
   template<class T1, T2> // change `result` accordingly.
   T1& operator() (std::pair<T1, T2>& pair)
   {
      return pair.first;
   }
   ...
```